# C# How to loop the maximum amount of times

Tags: c#, multithreading, optimization

When going through a really long array, or have a complicated calculations per each index, is there a way to yield after iterating through the array for the maximum amount of time. The maximum amount of time is the maximum time per each frame.

For example:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++){

   do something complicated;

   if(maximum amount of time /*right before the user feels lag*/)
      yield; (come back and resume i where it last yielded)
   }
}
//order does not matter
```

So basically, what I want to achieve is high percent usage for the cpu, however, I do not want it to go beyond 100%, which the user will experience lag

edit:
Sorry for the little confusion. A more clear example might be 3d rendering in a program such as blender. When the user hits render, it calculates each pixels to determine what color it needs to be. When one looks at the cpu usage, it is close to 100%. however, it does not freeze while it calculates the pixels while it calculates the maximum amount as possible

Comment: Sorry for the little confusion. A more clear example might be 3d rendering in a program such as blender. When the user hits render, it calculates each pixels to determine what color it needs to be. When one looks at the cpu usage, it is close to 100%. however, it does not freeze while it calculates the pixels while it calculates the maximum amount as possible

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are running your code on multiple CPUs (as implied by the `multithreading` tag), there should (in the usual case) be no need to stop executing the loop in order for your user interface to remain responsive.  Perform the calculation on one or more background threads, and have those background threads update the UI thread as appropriate.

> is there a way to yield after iterating through the array for the maximum amount of time

If by yield you mean just stop (and restart from the beginning next frame), then sure.  You can pass a [CancellationToken](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken(v=vs.110).aspx) to your thread, and have it periodically check for a cancellation request.  You can use a timer at the start of each frame to fire off that request, or more likely, use an existing mechanism that already does end-of-frame processing to trigger the thread to stop work.

If by yield you mean stop where I am and resume at that place at the start of the next frame, I would ask why stop given that you have multiple CPUs.  If you must stop, you can use the CancellationToken as before, but just keep track of where you are in the loop, resuming from there instead of at the start.

> So basically, what I want to achieve is high percent usage for the cpu, however, I do not want it to go beyond 100%, which the user will experience lag

You can never go over 100% CPU usage by definition.  To avoid the feeling of lag when the CPU utilization is high, use [thread priorities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.priority%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to ensure that the foreground thread has a higher priority than your background threads.

Comment: I still think a push model approach (with Observable pattern) would fit perfectly for this scenario. Anyway, this seems to work alright.

Comment: Sorry for the little confusion. A more clear example might be 3d rendering in a program such as blender. When the user hits render, it calculates each pixels to determine what color it needs to be. When one looks at the cpu usage, it is close to 100%. however, it does not freeze while it calculates the pixels while it calculates the maximum amount as possible.   So, does multitasking solve this? Does it automatically handle the cpu usage? Sorry I am new to multithreading and I am clueless

Comment: @shuao23 Using PLINQ with the CancellationToken might be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something....

```
 double MAX_PROCESSTIME = 50.0;

 DateTime loopStart = DateTime.Now();
 for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++){

   // do something complicated;

   double timePassed = (DateTime.Now() - loopStart).TotalMilliseconds;
   if(timePassed  > MAX_PROCESSTIME) 
   {
       break;
   }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the thread is already blocked by "// do somehing complicated;" and all of that has to finish before MAX_PROCESSTIME is evaluated.

Comment: I'm not sure that is the actual problem.  If it is, "do something complicated" must check for time expired (or for a CancellationToken to flag time's up) rather than the loop body.  If you're doing "something complicated" 100,000 times per frame, it seems unlikely that you have to interrupt in the middle of processing 1/100,000th of the total work.  But then, maybe my read is off.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the solution to this problem is to move the work to a separate thread that can't interrupt the UI, and let the UI or a controller thread cancel the work when called for.

Another option is that I've read somewhere typical humans have a perception level of about 25 milliseconds; two events are perceived to occur at the same time as long as they are less than 25 milliseconds apart. Sadly, I can no longer find the original reference, but I did at least find [a corroborating article](http://www.wired.com/2013/02/john-carmacks-latency-mitigation-strategies/). You can use this fact to set a timer for about that long and let the process run as much as you want until the timer goes off. You may also want to account for the atypical human as well, especially if your app is in an area catering to people that may have above average reflexes.

Answer (score 0):

How about you consider use a push model instead, to iterate in parallel and raising an event so the consumer just treat each item as they come?